# How to get rid of spell checker on macOS Mojave?

Tags: macos, mojave, spellcheck

I have disabled spell checker in System Preferences > Keyboard > Text.
Also, in TextEdit, under Edit > Grammar > Check spelling automatically.

Opening a document in TextEdit keeps re-enabling the app-level spell checker itself, again and again.

I am not using macOS in English. Running macOS Mojave 10.14.3

How can I get rid of this? I remember this was a bug in some previous Mac OS X version. It has been fixed back in the day.

Comment: It seems to set it per document, which is a bit irritating - I worked out a script to toggle it a while ago - not tested it since - https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/209219/85275

Comment: Did you also disable in TextEdit > Preferences?

Comment: What language are you using macOS in then?

Comment: @TomGewecke oh my. I didn't know that can be also found in app settings. I never opened them tbh. Thanks, solved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TextEdit has yet a 3rd place where you might need to turn this off, TextEdit > Preferences > New Document > Options