# Disable mac autocorrect for imessage via terminal/defaults write

Tags: terminal, defaults

I have already disabled system's autocorrect feature with

```
defaults write com.apple.notes NSAutomaticSpellingCorrectionEnabled -bool false
```

However I still can see autocorrect enabled in iMessage:

[image]

I know I can just click on it, but I would like to have a computer set up script which would disable this via terminal and `defaults write`. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: It seems all those checkers are enabled not only per app, but also per document. I'm not sure there is a way to ensure it is always off, everywhere. See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373113/always-enable-smart-quotes-in-textedit for a similar situation with TextEdit