# How to disable smart quotes?

Tags: macos, big-sur

I disabled smart quotes in System Preferences, and I am trying to do this in every app. For example in TextEdit they're disabled. In Xcode they were already disabled but as I tried to change anything in Edit -> Format -> Substitutions, the whole menu became disabled.

But nothing to do: they are still used in TextEdit, in Xcode and in any app. Why is it so hard? Does anybody know how to disable them?

[image]

Comment: In **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Text**, **for Double Quotes**  and **for Single Quotes** have you set them to _straight quotes_, e.g. **"abc"** and **'abc'**?

Comment: TextEdit remembers smart quote status **by document**. To fight it you need something like this - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373113/always-enable-smart-quotes-in-textedit/373150#373150

Comment: @user3439894 I added a screenshot. This is how my preferences look like.

Comment: In **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Text**, set **for Double Quotes** and **for Single Quotes** to _straight quotes_, e.g. **"abc"** and **'abc'**, then it shouldn't matter whether or not a _substitution_ occurs as it will be _straight quotes_, assuming of course that is what.

Comment: TextEdit has the pref in 2 places; one for new documents, one for the current frontmost document. This second pref is stored in the document itself, hence my earlier comment.

Comment: @user3439894 Even if not directly by doing what I wanted to do (disabling smart quotes), your comment solved the problem. If you turn it into an answer I will accept it.

Comment: @user3439894 Disregard my previous comment. It doesn't solve the problem for cases like "a -> ä

Comment: What structure are you using that would turn "a into ä? The standard way to generate ä is option/U, A.

Comment: @Tetsujin If I type a double quote and then 'a' without pressing space in-between, then I get a 'ä', regardless if smart quotes are enabled or not in system preferences. I get it in any app.

Comment: What input language are you using? It sounds like you're using `International - PC` which is the only input I know that does that. I'd really suggest using *anything* except that one ;) See https://superuser.com/a/1498953/347380 for how it's usually done