# Is there a way to disable smart quotes even if the app sets its own substitutions?

Tags: keyboard, text-input

I need to force an application (Collections) to not use smart quotes and other text substitutions. I have disabled the option in system-wide preferences and other applications respect it, but Collections not only ignores the system-wide preference, but also re-enables the Smart Quotes, Smart Dashes and Text Substitution options under its own Edit menu whenever I open a new dialog.

Is there a way in Mac OS to forcibly override this behavior? Or is my only recourse reporting a bug in the application?

Comment: idk Collections, but check the Edit menu. Many apps have their own Substitutions settings that can override global [sometime even per document, which is what TextEdit does.]

Comment: @Tetsujin that's the thing - the app has those settings, but (maybe due to shoddy programming, maybe some odd logic) keeps setting them back to "Enabled". I'll open an entry to edit it, disable smart quotes, edit and save, and when I open it, or another entry, again the option is quietly enabled. I'm hoping there's a way to either ignore the app's setting, or somehow modify whatever default it's restoring.

Comment: Have a look at https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373113/always-enable-smart-quotes-in-textedit for a way to do it in TextEdit which you could perhaps adapt. TextEdit saves this setting per document, so you have to be fairly aggressive with it ;)